# Basic usage of conditionals with std::atomic<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

So I'm starting to familiarize myself with C++11 `<atomic>` types.  In the past, when I had an atomic flag I would usually simply lock a mutex before accessing it.  A common need would be to check if the flag is `false`, and if so, atomically set it to `true` and then do something.  So basically this would be accomplished like this, where `flag` is a simple `bool`:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    if (!flag) 
    {
        flag = true;
        // do something;
    }
}
```

So, now I'm trying to figure out how the same thing can be accomplished with `<atomic>`.  The [**docs**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) say that the assignment operator and `operator T` of an atomic type are atomic operations.  However, if I change `flag` to `std::atomic<bool>`, I imagine I can't simple say:

```
if (!flag)
{
  flag = true;
  // do something
}
```

... because even though the expression `(!flag)` is atomic, and the assignment `flag = true` is atomic, there's nothing to prevent another thread from modifying flag in between those two statements.

So, if I understand correctly here, the only proper usage - ***at all*** - of conditionals with atomic types, where the result of the conditional could modify the atomic variable, is to use the Compare and Swap operation?  Am I correct?

So, I'd have to say:

```
bool expected = false;
if (flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true))
{
   // do something
}
```

Am I correct in my understanding here?

Comment: [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) exists for exactly the use case you're describing, and what's more it's guaranteed to be lock-free on all platforms. You would use the `test_and_set` method, which is atomic. You could also use a `std::atomic<int>` and perform a `fetch_add` on it, which is atomic and will give you the previous value at the time the increment is done (this is often faster than a CAS on most architectures, though I imagine no faster than `std::atomic_flag`, which would be my preference in this case).

Comment: Right - but it seems there is no way to simply atomically "check" the value of an atomic flag (without setting it) - or is there?  The docs don't define an `operator bool` or whatever that would enable the expression `if (flag)`.  I realize I didn't specify that requirement in my question - I'm just wondering.  Speaking of which... why *isn't* there a way to simply check the atomic flag without setting it?

Comment: That's right, you have to set it in order to test it (which is equivalent to your sample code as it's currently written, except that it's atomic). If you need to test it indenpendently I suggest using the `fetch_add` approach, or `compare_exchange_strong` (which is much clearer, and is [just as fast as `fetch_add` (`lock xadd`) on x86](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)).

Comment: @Cameron using of `std::atomic_flag` in any platform and in any data-types and also in x86 or x64 is possible without any problem? i mean, can we use of `std::atomic_flag` either in linux and windows and either in x86 and x64 without memory trouble in variables?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi: `std::atomic_flag` is guaranteed to be lock-free by the C++11+ standard. So on all platforms that provide support for C++11 or above, it should be lock-free, otherwise the compiler/libraries are not conformant. In particular, all major compilers on Linux and Windows (both 32- and 64-bit) provide an efficient, lock-free `std::atomic_flag`.

Comment: @Cameron sorry i have got another question, and cannot ask here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have multiple threads that are running the same code that need to do that flip, yes - you will need to use `compare_exchange_weak()` or `compare_exchange_strong()` for the precisely the reason you suggest (probably prefer strong).

However, it's not the case to say that this is the **only** proper usage of conditionals with atomics. If I have, say, one thread that only ever reads the atomic and one that writes to it, it's perfectly reasonable to use them the simple way... e.g.:

```
std::atomic<bool> done{false};

// thread 1
while (!done) {
    ....
}

// thread 2
stop() { done = true; }
```

There's no reason for me to do a `done.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)` there. That's overkill. It's really on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: It's clear from the OP's code that `compare_exchange_{weak,strong}` is appropriate in this case. The question does qualify the word "only" with the condition that the result of the comparison will be used to decide whether the assignment occurs. Still, good thorough answer for the wider set of use cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

That being said, you may prefer `compare_exchange_strong` for this, unless you're in a tight loop. It can lead to reduced performance but is guaranteed to give you the result you expect (which `compare_exchange_weak` is not).

Answer (score 0):

Obvious note: lock semantics is quite different to just atomic check since in this case the other thread waits until lock released and will always perform its actions after lock is acquired. So, strictly speaking two code examples are not equivalent.